# Retrieving Storefront Access token

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to make a request to the storefront_access_tokens.json endpoint. I have it setup properly and am sending a proper Access Token in the header. I keep getting this error:

```
{
  "errors": "App must have a channel record to create a storefront access token."
}
```

The store DOES have a sales channel but this error seems to indicate that the app must have one. This is extremely confusing and there isn't much useful information on how to resolve it.

Comment: Is your APP set as a sales channel? The app credentials you are using must be a sales channel (not a private app) but you must go in your partner app dashboard and switch it to a sales channel.

Comment: @drip I don't understand how the app could be a sales channel? Doesn't that need approval by Shopify? It's a "custom app" with the proper scope added to the store. Also confused by "partner app dashboard and switch to a sales channel", I honestly just want a storefront token so that I can use the API. lol...this is a LOT of extra extra for something so basic.

Comment: I haven't used this specific API end-point, but from their docs it seems that your app must be a sales channel. So in order to make it a sales channel go to https://partners.shopify.com/ go to `Apps -> Your App -> App Setup` there is a section there `Turn your app into a sales channel` where you click a button and you are ready. I don't remember if you had to reinstall your app afterwards, but that is the process to turn it to a Sales Channel. I had a similar issue when I had to use the Checkout API and turning it to a Sales channel allowed me to use it.

Comment: Please have in mind that if you JUST want the Storefront API Access Token, it's better to create a Private app for this and use the generated Access Token there. I just assumed that you need it to be dynamic for each store since you were using that end-point. You don't need Custom app for this approach at all and it's a hell lot easier.

Comment: @drip what the hell! Yeah this is ONLY for one store. So a private app is almost like a one-off use and a custom app is more for applying to multiple stores? This is my first time working with Shopify's API and it's SUCH a docs breakfast. Ridiculous for a company their size.

Comment: Private Apps and Custom Apps (there are differences but I wont go in details) can be used for only one store, public Apps can be used for multiply stores. If you plan to only use the Storefront API then use a Private App and ditch the custom app, you don't need it. The Private app generates the Storefront Access Token for you, so you only need to create the app from your store `/admin/apps/private` and check a checkbox `Allow this app to access your storefront data using the Storefront API` aaaand that's all. :) Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @drip. Sigh. Honestly I'm disappointed in Shopify right now. This shouldn't be such a horrid process. Barf.